# How can I write C++ fstream to file?

Tags: c++, fstream, writetofile

I have a problem with this code. Could you please help me to find out why it does not save new total donation values (total) to the file (donation_total.txt)? It should be noted that the default value saved in the file is zero, but it keeps it for each iteration. I need the new value is saved at the last line each time.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

fstream records;
records.open("donation_total.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::app);
if (records.is_open())
{
    cout << "The record file is open!" << endl;
    string line;
    while (!records.eof())
    {
        getline(records, line);
    }
    int total = stoi(line);
    cout << "Total donation is: "<<total << endl;
    cout << "Is there any new record?" << endl;
    string str,newname;
    stringstream field;
    string name;
    int donation;
    getline(cin , str);
    while (str=="Yes" | str=="yes")
    {
        cout << "Enter name and donation value: ";
        getline(cin, newname);
        field.str(newname);
        field >> name >> donation;
        total += donation;
        field.clear();
        cout << name << " donates " << donation << "$" << endl;
        cout << "Total donation is: " << total << endl;
        records << endl << total;
        cout << "Is there any new record?" << endl;
        getline(cin, str);
    }
}
else
{
    cerr << "Could not find the file!" << endl;
}
records.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (!records.eof())` Where did you learn this way? We need to correct it.

Comment: `while ( str == "Yes" | str == "yes")` this also might be wrong, you probably want `||` (logical "or")  instead of `|` (binary "or")

Comment: Why use stringstream if you have an fstream type of file?

Answer (score 0):

Your program has many logical incorrectness. When a name is entered with no donation amount, it takes the previously donated value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    fstream records;
    records.open("donation_total.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ios_base::app);

    if (records.is_open())
    {
        cout << "The record file is open!" << endl;
        string line;

        while (getline(cin, line))
        {
            int total = stoi(line);
            cout << "Total donation is: "<<total << endl;
            cout << "Is there any new record?" << endl;
            string str,newname;
            stringstream field;
            string name;
            int donation;
            getline(cin , str);
            while (str=="Yes" || str=="yes")
            {
                cout << "Enter name and donation value: ";
                getline(cin, newname);
                field.str(newname);
                field >> name >> donation;
                total += donation;
                field.clear();
                cout << name << " donates " << donation << "$" << endl;
                cout << "Total donation is: " << total << endl;
                records << endl << total;
                cout << "Is there any new record? ";
                getline(cin, str);
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Could not find the file!" << endl;
    }
    records.close();

return 0;
}
```

[image: Files Program]

Comment: Thanks, it works. But now the problem is that I want the last amount of total donation which has saved before in the file is read automatically not be imported by the user each time as it is in while (getline(cin,line)). How can I fix it?